# How to make ValueListenableBuilder can be assigned as an Icon?

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, flutter-widget

I was trying to use ValueListanableBuilder as a parameter to child widget, previously it was an Icon, and I calling this child multiple times on parent widget with Icon but I need to pass a child with ValueListanableBuilder once.

I have tried to remove data types `Icon icon;` and use `final icon` but it gives me warning `Prefer typing uninitialized variables and fields. dart(prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables)`.

How can I use `ValueListanableBuilder` for `Icon` data type as a constructor for child widget.

Code Snippet Example:

```
// CameraScreen ( Parent )
...
CameraButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new));
...

// CameraScreen ( Child )
...
class CameraButton extends StatelessWidget {
  Icon icon;
  CameraButton({ required this.icon });
...
```

Comment: Please show your expected widget struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CameraScreen ( Parent )

```
class CameraScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CameraButton(
      icon: ValueListenableBuilder<Icon>(
        valueListenable: ValueNotifier(Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new)),
        builder: (_, __, ___) {
          // TODO: implement build
          throw UnimplementedError();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CameraScreen ( Child )

```
class CameraButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraButton({Key? key, required this.icon}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```